# SCD type-2 using dynamic cache Informatica

Tags: informatica, scd

I am trying to implement a SCD type2 in informatica and I am finding it difficult to achieve this, reason being multiple records in the source for the same key. 
In case of multiple records, I have to use dynamic cache and when I do, it doesn't identify the correct record when looked up as I don't have surrogate key calculated when dynamic lookup is performed. So, this is what happens:

My source has 3 records for the same key and target doesn't have anything in it.
Dynamic look up is performed with the key and 1st record is identified as Insert and have the active flag set to "Y". Then the 2nd record is looked up and identified as update and the active flag is set to "Y" for it and "N" for the 1st record. When the 3rd record comes in, lookup is not able to identify the latest record set to "Y", but fetched the 1st record again and set it to "N" while setting the 3rd record to "Y". As a result, I have 2 active records now for the same key which fails to meet the type-2 requirement.

Please help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm guessing its the first run of that SCD, I can suggest you use last record implement(with expression using variable below other that uses them) and then checks if the ID need to be updated,take the last one and make in not active.

Comment: To implement SCD2 you need a Key. If you've got two rows with same key  - then it's not a key. You'll never know what to update. Find a key. In the worst case you may end up with almost all columns as a key. Or even all of them being a key. Anyway: you need a key.

Comment: He can also add a key(new column) which will be unique key for the SCD